# Read one number from file into Variable in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to know how to read a number from a file to a variable. Anyone able to help please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the entire file's contents is the number, I'd use `File::read` to get the contents of the file and `String#to_i` to convert the resulting string to an integer.

So:

```
number = File.read('filename.txt').to_i
```

Answer (score 1):

If your file has a string or variable length of characters that has some numbers in it then you can get all the numbers using regex and assign it to your variable e.g.

```
file_contents = File.read('filename') # => "a string of character with 23 number and 123 in it"
numbers = file_contents.scan(/\d+/) # => ['23', '123']
```

To convert the above array of string numbers to integer

```
numbers.collect! &:to_i # => [23, 123]
```

Then you can assign these number to any variable you want

```
number1 = numbers.first
number2 = numbers.last
```

Comment: I tried the code you posted above and come up with some errors on my end. 

the line 

numbers.collect! &:to_i

gives the error  wrong argument type Symbol (expected Proc) (TypeError)

Comment: this symbol to_proc is added in ruby 1.8.7 so probably you are running ruby 1.8.6. Try this code then
    numbers.collect!{|num| num.to_i}